# how to get content of an element with HTML nodes?

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I need to get the content of an element and place that content into another element. I use `createTextNode` to append that content as a child to the target element.

As I append it as text node, `<` and `>` is converted into `&lt;` and `&gt;`. How can I append that content without conversion?

**For example:**

```
<li id="fn1">
<div>
<a>some text
</a>
</div>
</li>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<p>
<div>
    <a>some text
    </a>
</div>
</p>
```

But my output is like,

```
<p>
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;a&gt;some text&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</p>
```

**my code**

```
$ch=dom->createElement("p");
$li=$xp->query("//li[contains(@id, 'fn')]");
  foreach($li as $liv) {
    $linodes = $liv->childNodes;
    $pvalue="";
       foreach ($linodes as $lin) {                                
       $pvalue.=$dom->saveXML($lin);}
$ch->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($pvalue)); }
```

I have tried,
`$ch->appendChild($dom->createTextNode(htmlspecialchars_decode($pvalue)));` but same output

Comment: You can use `htmlspecialchars_decode` to output as the HTML should.

Comment: I tried it like, `$ch->appendChild($dom->createTextNode(htmlspecialchars_decode($pvalue))); ` but same output as it appended as textnode, or else where should I use that function in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to

- *move* a node within the same document: remove that node via [DOMNode::removeChild](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) and append the return value of that function via [DOMNode::appendChild](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) to its new parent node.
- *copy* the node to a new location within the same document, make a deep clone of the node via [DOMNode::clone](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domnode.clonenode.php) the node and append it.
- *transfer* the node to another document, import that node to the new document via [DOMDOcument::importNode](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) and then append it to its new parent.

Comment: Thank you!  where to use `cloneNode(true)` in my code?

Comment: which of the three scenarios is it in your case? move,copy or transfer?

Comment: Need to copy the nodes(content) of specific element to the target element

Comment: It works! I tried `$pvalue=$liv->cloneNode(True);$ch->appendChild($pvalue)`. Thank you so much

Comment: One more query. cloneNode gets including parentNode, not ly content of the parentNode. What to do for this?

Comment: ?? Sorry, I don't understand the last comment? What do you mean?